# Getting youtube live event rtmp url and stream name

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

How can I get rtmp url and stream name for particular live event?

Previously I've been using Youtube API v.2.0 and could retrieve the list of live events which contained both rtmp urls and stream names. With the new Youtube Live Streaming API (v.3.0) I can retrieve the list of live events using `liveBroadcasts` list method, but the response doesn't contain any rtmp urls and stream names. In order to get them I should create a new `liveStream` resource or use an existing one.

Is there any way to get rtmp url and stream name without doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, you have to create liveStream. Broadcast is only the event object, whereas stream is your connection point.
Here are some examples: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#examples

Comment: BTW, I've realized that `liveBroadcast` has `boundStreamId` property, so maybe I do not have to create my own `liveStream` in order to get the rtmp url, I can request for `liveStream` with id = `boundStreamId`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.liveStreams.list({
      "part": [
        "snippet,cdn,contentDetails,status"
        //"cdn"
      ],
      "mine": true
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
                
                var responseData = JSON.stringify(response);
                alert(responseData);
                
                //alert(response.result.items);
                
                var itemsArr = response.result.items;
                var itemObj = itemsArr[0];
                alert('streamName = ' + itemObj.cdn.ingestionInfo.streamName);
                
                //alert(responseData.result);
                //var result = responseData.result;
                
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Comment: It might have been very late but somehow i landed onto this question and posted my view/answer. It may help someone in this community.

Comment: It will give you error if you run this snippet. So, better you copy this code and create your own small project and try it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.